# Using a custom field with different names

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, form, custom-field, xml

I want to use a flexible field name for a field across different forms thru my extension.

My custom example field looks like this:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Form\FormHelper;

FormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');

class JFormFieldExample extends \JFormFieldList
{

    public $type = 'Example';
    protected static $options = array();    
    protected function getOptions()

    {
        // Accepted modifiers
        $hash = md5($this->element);

        if (!isset(static::$options[$hash]))
        {
            static::$options[$hash] = parent::getOptions();

            $db = Factory::getDbo();

            $options[] = JHTML::_('select.option', '1', JText::_('1'), 'value', 'text');
            $options[] = JHTML::_('select.option', '2', JText::_('2'), 'value', 'text');
        }

        return static::$options[$hash];
    }
}
```

When using it inside a form xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
    <fieldset addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_mycomp/models/fields">    
        <field name="example" multiple="multiple" type="example" default="0"  label="example" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

it gets outputted like this:

```
<?php echo $this->form->getLabel('example'); ?>
<div class="form-controls">
    <?php echo $this->form->getInput('example');?>
</div>
```

and this is the name of the field that gets outputted:

```
jform[example]
```

I want to use that field in different scenarios where field names like this should be possible:

```
jform[example]
jform[example][]
jform[table1][example][]
```

How can this be accomplished?

if changing the XML to this:

```
<field name="[table1][example]" multiple="multiple" type="example" default="0"  label="example" />
```

i get this:

```
jform[[table1][example]][]
```

Comment: I guess I'm confused. different scenarios are produced by different form XML definitions. So if you write the xml for a form that uses the custom field that way, it'll get rendered that way. If you use the same xml, you get the same output.

Answer (score 0):

> jform[example][]

This would depend on whether the field has `multiple` attribute enabled or not. In your case it does so it already should look like this.

> jform[table1][example][]

Put the field in a field group:

```
<fields name="table1">
    <field name="example" multiple="multiple" type="example" default="0"  label="example" />
</fields>
```